# C++ Template Metaprogramming- not sure I quite get the fuss?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

As I understand it normal C++ code is translated into assembler at compile time, which is then executed by the CPU at run-time. So I do not quite understand what the fuss is with the advantages of template metaprogramming?

Wikipedia says the following about template metaprogramming:

> Template metaprogramming is a metaprogramming technique in which
>   templates are used by a compiler to generate temporary source code,
>   which is merged by the compiler with the rest of the source code and
>   then compiled. The output of these templates include compile-time
>   constants, data structures, and complete functions. The use of
>   templates can be thought of as compile-time execution.

This didn't really seem to emphasise the advantages of template metaprogramming to me...?

I'm asking because I am interested in what template metaprogramming could do for optimizing/improving efficiency of low latency C++ applications. I have probably not understood something correctly along the way, so please feel free to correct my understanding.

Comment: You won't understand it until you need to do it.

Comment: @SethCarnegie do you have any examples where you have found it extremely useful?

Comment: @user997112 matrix multiplication is one application where the use of template metaprogramming can avoid many costly temporaries in complex expressions involving matrix operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you read the zillions of articles out there that thoroughly discuss TM? For example:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3743/A-gentle-introduction-to-Template-Metaprogramming
- http://aszt.inf.elte.hu/~gsd/halado_cpp/ch06s04.html
- http://blog.lorentey.hu/2010/04/21/cpp-template-metaprogramming/
- etc, etc.

A simple way of looking at (one kind) of template metaprogramming is as "strong" memoization. A common example is the following:

Lets say your program needs the compute a factorial for some number. With TM you can compute the factorial in compile-time, which increases compile time (and binary size) but decreases runtime. The example code is from the 2nd site above; if you were doing it the "naive" way, you'd have code that looks like:

```
int factorial( int n) {
    return (n==0) ? 1 : n*factorial(n-1)l
}

int main() {
    cout << factorial(5) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

With TM we can compute the factorial at compile-time:

```
// factorial.cpp

#include <iostream>

template <int N>
struct Factorial {
    enum { value = N * Factorial<N-1>::value };
};

template <>
struct Factorial<1> {
    enum { value = 1 };
};

// example use
int main() {
    const int fact5 = Factorial<15>::value;
    std::cout << fact5 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here `Factorial<15>::value` is essentially a compile-time constant. As always, simplistic examples aren't particularly useful, but hopefully you get the gist of it.

Comment: Ok but the fact does remain that this would be only useful if I always wanted to know factorial 15 in my run-time execution? I appreciate it was a simple example- but (the factorial example is the usual example for explaining TMP) if I had a calculator with a factorial button, I could have just declared a const int and then used my calculator to get he value, rather than writing all that code?

Comment: You're right; this is what TM is very often used for: generating compile-time lookup tables. Even though this may seem trivial, there are clever TM implementations of stuff like crc32 and md5 (that take advantage of similarly-constructed lookup tables) that increase hashing performance noticeably. Consider a calculation that's not as simple as doing `5!` on your calculator.

Comment: @user997112 so each time you needed a new factorial, you would get your calculator, calculate the number, type it into your program, instead of writing `Factorial<TheNumber>::value`?

Comment: @juanchopanza from what I understand, you need to know at compile time what factorial number you wish to calculate? Otherwise how will the compiler know which factorial values (eg n) it would calculate? I'll change the value of my const int and you'd change the value of your template parameter?

Comment: @user997112 Yes. I need 345 factorial. I use a template. You have to calculate it first, then put it into your code. If you want to do that, then fine.

Comment: @user997112: It's also more expressive to use a template. Consider `12!` which happens to be `479001600`. You'll have `const long blah = 479001600`. What does that mean to anyone? I'll have `const long blah = Factorial<12>::value` -- I guess you could add a comment, but then you have to change comments every time you change values. Using templates has clear advantages here.

Answer (score 0):

Another example would be how to calculate the Fibonacci Sequence.

Normal recursive way to do it :

```
uint64_t fibonacci(int n) {
    if (n <= 2)
        return 1;
    else
        return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
}
```

Using metaprogramming :

```
template< int n > struct Fibonacci {
    static const uint64_t value = Fibonacci< n-1 >::value +  Fibonacci< n-2 >::value;
};

template<> struct Fibonacci< 1 > {
    static const uint64_t value = 1;
};

template<> struct Fibonacci< 0 > {
    static const uint64_t value = 0;
};
```

Now you can try by yourself to call `fibonacci(80)` or `Fibonacci<80>::value`. The recursive function will probably not work and crash, the one using metaprogramming will be perfectly fine and quite fast.

Comment: how does the Compiler avoid the big recursion (without tail recursion)?